# Point-E in Unity

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, stable-diffusion

I'm looking for a way to get [Point-E](https://github.com/openai/point-e) running in Unity.

My plan is to make a 3D model generator with a text prompt, however, I can't really figure out how. I was able to run it in Google Colab, as well as in a Jupyter Notebook (after following some tutorials), but I would need to run the code locally, and I've attempted running the same Google Colab codes in Python/Anaconda but haven't had much luck. I'm not too familiar with Python and the like.

Or maybe is there an API that I can Post/GET to in order to get a JSON containing the points/colour data?

I tried https://replicate.com/cjwbw/point-e/api but I have no idea how to simply call the API in Unity, I tried in Python and again, it doesn't work? It says to export the API code in Python, but it simply says the "export" command could not be found.

Basically I plan to make a plugin where users can generate a model based on a text prompt, but I feel like I'm in way over my head.

Any ideas on how to fix this?